# Differences using ajax or post back to post actions

Tags: jquery, ajax, c#-4.0, postback, asp.net-4.0

So my question is a little weird, as I did not learn about it (ajax approach)

I just reused an original function that I encountered, renamed and tested the function.

**So in other different scenario** (more common):

A few `<asp:TextBox>` controls, one submit button.

What is the advantage of Ajax over c# asp.net PostBack?

This is the code

```
 function AppsName_AjxUpdt(CurrentColumn, recNumSplited, newValue, TBX, ActionRequest, RecordNum) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'YourPageNameHere.aspx',
            data: {
                'PostSentByAjax': "true",
                'CurrentColumn': CurrentColumn,
                'recNumSplited': recNumSplited,
                'value': newValue,
                'ActionRequest': ActionRequest
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                if (type == "UpdateUserID") {
                    TBX.setAttribute(defaultValue, newValue);

                    refreshData();
                }
                if (type == "reason") {
                    window.form1.submit();
                }

                if (type == "delete") {
                    document.getElementById("row_" + rowid).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("totalMins").innerHTML = "<span style='text-decoration:underline;color:#A7C942;cursor:pointer;' onclick='refreshData();'>Refresh Results</span>";
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

So how different is this code-behavior Vs binding an `<asp:TextBox>` to autopostback feature?
I could just say what I *did* notes,...the advantage I could see is:

Only if you would like to create a dynamic table with embedded c# code within the tags so you could generate elements `id`'s `name`s and `value`s properties, and **in the same time** you want that control to post back by it's own event(and since there's no postback event  for `html controls`), and if you did apply c# codes within the scope of the tag it could not be while using an asp:TextBox only input type "text".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASP.NET `Postback` makes the page undergo a full `Page` lifecycle. 
The Ajax post is asyncronous and does not reload your page. In this sense no specific ASP.NET server events related to the page lifecycle would be fired if you issue your post using an Ajax call. So you would not get `Page_Init`, `Page_Load`, `Button` clicks or anything like that.

Comment: @KonstatinD-Infragistics , thanks i guess i should learn more about that , though i can understand that it is actually almost always better (unless u did (dont know why you would like that) want to have page go through a full Page-LifeCycle) other wise i assume that it's allways better to "make an effort" and use this method and prefer it over a simple no-hussle built-in and easy to use post back

Comment: i will consider what you added as update to your answer about Page events. i should ask my logic wether i need those events to fire on this specific action of a given control

Comment: @LoneXcoder Absolutely, if you need those events then you prefer a postback.