# What are the advantages of using postback instead of ajax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am new to asp.net web forms.  I have noticed that the postback is used to update the state of the page, however it updates the entire page.  Why isn't ajax used instead, since it doesn't require the entire page to be reloaded?
Does a postback have some advantages that ajax does not?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239587/differences-using-ajax-or-post-back-to-post-actions

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use Ajax if you prefer, depending on what you are trying to accomplish, using what it offers natively (e.g. [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), or not (plain Javascript or using a library like jquery, etc).

The `WebForms` model gives you scaffolding (or is it "abstraction"?) to work with request/response in a less "bare metal" way. You work with `server controls` "instead of" (aka abstraction) HTTP POST/GET, a sense of "persistence" (e.g. VIEWSTATE) and some features that mitigate risks that you'd have to deal with otherwise (e.g. validation of Viewstate, event validation and such). Underneath the covers, you'll find Javascript all over the place (part of the "magic sauce")

There are pros and cons to it, just like anything else. You decide what each pro and con mean to your objective.

If you'd rather work in a more bare metal way, you *can* - well, yes, you can still work with bare HTTP POST or GET in WebForms, after all it is a `POST`back, and clicking on a link to get to some WebForm is a `GET`, though that probably isn't the most effective way (going against the grain of WebForms model), or look into ASP.Net MVC, WebPages.

Hth...